# (Merge sort) The code is printing nothing

Tags: c, mergesort

I recently started learning algorithm with C. I tried to implement `merge_sort`. But the code is printing nothing and I can't find the problem why this happening. If you take a look at the code and give me the solution it would be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Note: Here I didn't give the `main` function. Only the `merge_sort()` and `merge()` functions

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int a[], int l[], int r[]);

void merge_sort(int a[], int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        int i;
        int mid = (n - 1) / 2;
        int l[mid], r[n - mid];
        for (i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            l[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (i = mid; i < n; i++) {
            r[i - mid] = a[i];
        }
        merge_sort(l, mid);
        merge_sort(r, n - mid);
        merge(a, l, r);
    }
}

void merge(int a[], int l[], int r[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int nl = sizeof(l) / sizeof(l[0]);
    int nr = sizeof(r) / sizeof(r[0]);
    while (i < nl && j < nr) {
        if (l[i] < r[j]) {
            a[k] = l[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            a[k] = r[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i < nl) {
        a[k] = l[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < nr) {
        a[k] = r[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your code is printing nothing because your code don't have any printing statements. Also note that `int nl=sizeof(l)/sizeof(l[0]);` is not the right way to get the number of elements.

Comment: The function `marge` is not defined. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `int nl=sizeof(l)/sizeof(l[0]);` will certainly not do what you think it does in the confines of `l` being a function argument (and thus nothing more than a pointer); thus `sizeof(l)/sizeof(l[0])`. is the same as "size of a pointer to int divided by the size of an int". The same mistake is repeated in multiple locations.

Comment: Also note that `int mid = (n-1)/2; int l[mid],r[n-mid];` may invoke *undefined behavior* because `mid` will become `0` when `n` is `2` while size of variable-length array must be positive.

Comment: @MikeCAT It's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @WhozCraig It's working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compute the size of the arrays passed as parameters with `int nl = sizeof(l) / sizeof(l[0]);` because `sizeof(l)` is the size of a pointer to `int`, not that of the array.  `sizeof(l)` only evaluates to the size of the array when the definition of the array is in scope.

You should pass the sizes explicitly as arguments.

Also change the computation for `mid`: `int mid = n / 2;`

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int a[], int l[], int nl, int r[], int nr);

void merge_sort(int a[], int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        int i;
        int mid = n / 2;
        int l[mid], r[n - mid];
        for (i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            l[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (i = mid; i < n; i++) {
            r[i - mid] = a[i];
        }
        merge_sort(l, mid);
        merge_sort(r, n - mid);
        merge(a, l, mid, r, n - mid);
    }
}

void merge(int a[], int l[], int nl, int r[], int nr) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < nl && j < nr) {
        if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
            a[k] = l[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            a[k] = r[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < nl) {
        a[k] = l[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < nr) {
        a[k] = r[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```